# Convert a video with content type video/quicktime to video/mp4 using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, apache-tika, quicktime

I have a strange problem. I start with a video file recored with an iPhone. The output is `video.mov`. I convert this to mp4 using ffmpeg:

`ffmpeg -i video.mov -vcodec h264 -acodec aac video.mp4`

If I use a tool like exiftool to show the metadata the output for `content-type` is `video/mp4` all seems to be correct. But my backend, which receives the video, uses a library called Apache Tika to extract the content type and the result here is: `video/quicktime`.

Scala code to retrieve the content type from the file:

```
// byteArray: Array[Byte]

val tika        = new TikaConfig()
val metadata    = new Metadata()
val contentType = tika.getDetector.detect(TikaInputStream.get(byteArray), metadata)
```

BTW: If I use a video editing program (DaVinci Resolve in my case) I can load the video, adjust settings and explicitly set the codec to mp4, export the video and then the resulting file works and Apache Tika extract the desired content-type. This is a workaround, but it does not scale and I like to automate this process via ffmpeg.

I'm stuck here. Can anyone give me a hint what I can do?

Versions:

tika: 1.22
ffmpeg: 4.4

ffmpeg log:

```
$ffmpeg -i video.mov -vcodec h264 -acodec aac video.mp4
ffmpeg version 4.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.4_2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-avresample --enable-videotoolbox
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'video.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt
    creation_time   : 2021-06-24T11:19:37.000000Z
    com.apple.quicktime.location.accuracy.horizontal: 65.000000
    com.apple.quicktime.location.ISO6709: +52.5554+013.3772+042.268/
    com.apple.quicktime.make: Apple
    com.apple.quicktime.model: iPhone 8
    com.apple.quicktime.software: 14.4.2
    com.apple.quicktime.creationdate: 2021-06-24T13:19:36+0200
  Duration: 00:00:09.83, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 7954 kb/s
  Stream #0:0(und): Video: hevc (Main) (hvc1 / 0x31637668), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 7810 kb/s, 30.01 fps, 30 tbr, 600 tbn, 600 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 90
      creation_time   : 2021-06-24T11:19:37.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : HEVC
    Side data:
      displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
  Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 96 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-06-24T11:19:37.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:2(und): Data: none (mebx / 0x7862656D), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-06-24T11:19:37.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Metadata
  Stream #0:3(und): Data: none (mebx / 0x7862656D), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-06-24T11:19:37.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Metadata
  Stream #0:4(und): Data: none (mebx / 0x7862656D), 34 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-06-24T11:19:37.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Metadata
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (hevc (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x7fbe08009400] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x7fbe08009400] profile High, level 4.0, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x7fbe08009400] 264 - core 163 r3060 5db6aa6 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2021 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt
    com.apple.quicktime.creationdate: 2021-06-24T13:19:36+0200
    com.apple.quicktime.location.accuracy.horizontal: 65.000000
    com.apple.quicktime.location.ISO6709: +52.5554+013.3772+042.268/
    com.apple.quicktime.make: Apple
    com.apple.quicktime.model: iPhone 8
    com.apple.quicktime.software: 14.4.2
    encoder         : Lavf58.76.100
  Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1080x1920, q=2-31, 30 fps, 15360 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.134.100 libx264
      creation_time   : 2021-06-24T11:19:37.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
      displaymatrix: rotation of -0.00 degrees
  Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 69 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-06-24T11:19:37.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : Lavc58.134.100 aac
frame=  295 fps= 18 q=-1.0 Lsize=    9980kB time=00:00:09.82 bitrate=8323.6kbits/s speed=0.614x
video:9884kB audio:85kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.103401%
[libx264 @ 0x7fbe08009400] frame I:6     Avg QP:21.84  size: 50301
[libx264 @ 0x7fbe08009400] frame P:217   Avg QP:24.23  size: 35435
[libx264 @ 0x7fbe08009400] frame B:72    Avg QP:24.97  size: 29582
[libx264 @ 0x7fbe08009400] consecutive B-frames: 66.8%  0.7%  4.1% 28.5%
[libx264 @ 0x7fbe08009400] mb I  I16..4:  6.7% 88.9%  4.4%
[libx264 @ 0x7fbe08009400] mb P  I16..4:  4.2% 32.9%  0.5%  P16..4: 49.6%  5.0%  2.3%  0.0%  0.0%    skip: 5.5%
[libx264 @ 0x7fbe08009400] mb B  I16..4:  0.9%  6.9%  0.0%  B16..8: 51.8%  7.7%  0.8%  direct:12.2%  skip:19.6%  L0:50.1% L1:46.9% BI: 3.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fbe08009400] 8x8 transform intra:87.7% inter:88.8%
[libx264 @ 0x7fbe08009400] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 59.2% 41.2% 0.9% inter: 38.3% 57.3% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fbe08009400] i16 v,h,dc,p: 15% 23%  8% 53%
[libx264 @ 0x7fbe08009400] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 16% 14% 29%  7%  8%  7%  7%  6%  6%
[libx264 @ 0x7fbe08009400] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 23% 18% 18%  9% 11%  7%  7%  4%  3%
[libx264 @ 0x7fbe08009400] i8c dc,h,v,p: 60% 20% 18%  1%
[libx264 @ 0x7fbe08009400] Weighted P-Frames: Y:3.2% UV:2.3%
[libx264 @ 0x7fbe08009400] ref P L0: 54.2% 10.7% 22.2% 12.5%  0.4%
[libx264 @ 0x7fbe08009400] ref B L0: 75.5% 19.6%  4.9%
[libx264 @ 0x7fbe08009400] ref B L1: 88.7% 11.3%
[libx264 @ 0x7fbe08009400] kb/s:8234.01
[aac @ 0x7fbe0802e000] Qavg: 446.889
```

Comment: Show full log from ffmpeg command. What is your tika version?

Comment: @llogan I added versions and ffmpeg log to the post

Comment: Unable to duplicate the issue using tika 1.2.6 or 2.0.0. Always shows `video/mp4`.

Comment: @llogan thanks for testing this out. I added the code snippet how the content type is retrieved from the byte array. Maybe this is not correct?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I only tested the command line utility `tika-app-*.jar`.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I did the same and yes, it shows video/mp4 as content type when I use tika-app.jar. Nevertheless the code snippet shown in my post still returns video/quicktime for the same video. Strange. I hope I find a solution.